# How can I replay the recorded audio in my JavaScript sketch?

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I have followed a tutorial which records audio for 3 seconds and automatically plays it back. It stored the audio in an array and turns into into a URL. I've added a button with the audio play function in it. So when you press the button it records and plays the audio automatically. My question is how can I add a second button to play and replay the audio. So I don't want it to play automatically when after it finished recording I only want it to play when a button is pressed.

It is all plain JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  button = createButton('Audio Hack');
  button.position(160, 180);
  button.mousePressed(audioHack);
  }

function audioHack() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.start();

      const audioChunks = [];
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      });

      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        audio.play();
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this by storing the audio in a global variable. Remove the `audio.play()`. Did you know p5.js has a beautiful p5.sound library that makes this super easy? https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundRecorder

```
let recorderAudio = null;    

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  button = createButton('Audio Hack');
  button.position(160, 180);
  button.mousePressed(audioHack);

  playButton = createButton('Play Audio');
  playButton.position(160, 200);
  playButton.mousePressed(function(){
    if (recordedAudio != null) recordedAudio.play();
  });
}

function audioHack() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.start();

      const audioChunks = [];
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      });

      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        recordedAudio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        //audio.play();
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. Yeah I did look at p5.sound but I'm doing a group exhibition so don't have a massive amount of control on what libraries I'm using so I'm trying to just use basic javascript where I can.

Comment: @Morgan Could you please share the complete code?